# how to use the following excel vba code?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub MergeRanges()
    Dim rng As Range, txt As String
    For Each rng In Selection
        txt = txt & rng.Value2
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Merge
    Selection = txt
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

when merge  cells, i want to remain all the data in the cells. i googled some time,finding the above code. but i don't know how to use it? and what's the meaning of them. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setup:

1. Open VBA editor (Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor) (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Insert > Module
3. Paste the code into your new module.

Use:

1. Select the cells you want to merge.
2. Tools > Macro > Macros... (shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>) > select `MergeRanges` > Run

If you want the macro to work with "special formats" such as dates, then you should change `.Value2` to `.Text`.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight some cells you want to merge (not dates or currency) and the press Alt+F8 an select this macro. It should (I didn't test) merge the cell contents into a cell without losing any of the contents that were in each cell.

Make sure to insert that code in the file first by pressing Alt+F11 to open VBE and right click the explorer and choose add module. Then paste this code in. Make sure your macro security is low enough to run it.

Answer (score 2):

- in Excel, press Alt-F8
- use the dialog to add an empty macro "MergeRanges"
- add your code above.
- To run the code, select some cells you want to merge, press Alt-F8 again and run that macro.